# Pegar em dados do array

Tags: array

Bom dia

Tenho o seguinte array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [UltimaAtualizacao] => 2017-04-20 16:15:00 [DataEntrada] => 2017-04-20 [Estado] => Finalizado [DataSaida] => [Relatorio] => Manutenção ) )
```

a minha duvida é como separo os dados do array em uma tabela com o nome por cima e o valor por baixo ?

Answer (score 0):

Solução

```
<tr>
    <td><?php print_r($rows[0]['ID']); ?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($rows[0]['DataEntrada']); ?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($rows[0]['UltimaAtualizacao']); ?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($rows[0]['Estado']); ?></td>
    <td><?php print_r($rows[0]['DataSaida']); ?></td>
    <td><center><img src="images/ico/Graphicloads-Filetype-Pdf.ico" width="30px" height="30px"</center></td>
</tr>
```